# Remove last character from first word in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, string

I need to remove the last character from first word in excel.

For example I have the cell B1 with "Teas from Spain" and I need cell A1 to be "Tea from Spain".

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can use `FIND` `MID` and `LEFT` for this:

```
=LEFT(B1,FIND(" ",B1)-2)&MID(B1,FIND(" ",B1),100)
```

First you need to find the first space in the text, then take everything to the left of this, apart form 1 character `LEFT(B1,FIND(" ",B1)-2)`

Then you add on (&) everything to the right of the first space, again use `FIND` to locate the space, then use this as the starting character in `MID`

`MID(B1,FIND(" ",B1),100)`

Rather than `MID` you could have used `LEN` and `RIGHT` also, I will leave you to work out how that could work ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use Replace:

```
=REPLACE(B1,FIND(" ",B1&" ")-1,1,"")
```

Which finds the first space and removes the character before that.

[image]